# Algebraic transformation with matrices and vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I came across this:

$\begin{align}
e &= \left\lVert M\vec{a}_i - \vec{z}_i\right\rVert^2\\
&=\vec{a}_i^\text{T}M^\text{T}M\vec{a}_i-\vec{z}_i^\text{T}M\vec{a}_i-\vec{a}_i^\text{T}M^\text{T}\vec{z}_i-\vec{z}_i^\text{T}\vec{z}_i\\
\nabla \vec{a}_ie & =2 M^\text{T}M\vec{a}_i-2M^\text{T}\vec{z}_i\overset{!}{=}0
\end{align}$

When I looked at it I thought: "Why no $M^2$, or something like that?" I had to admit I don't know how to properly do this by myself.

So please enlighten me on this topic.

Comment: \begin{align*} 
\left\lVert M\vec{a}_i - \vec{z}_i\right\rVert^2 &= \Big(M\vec{a}_i - \vec{z}_i\Big)^T\Big( M\vec{a}_i - \vec{z}_i\Big),\\
&= \Big( (M\vec{a}_i)^T - \vec{z}_i^T\Big)\Big( M\vec{a}_i - \vec{z}_i\Big),\\
&= \Big( \vec{a}_i^TM^T - \vec{z}_i^T\Big)\Big( M\vec{a}_i - \vec{z}_i\Big),\\
&= \vec{a}_i^TM^TM\vec{a}_i -\vec{a}_i^TM^T\vec{z}_i - \vec{z}_i^T M\vec{a}_i + \vec{z}_i^T\vec{z}_i,\\
&= \vec{a}_i^TM^TM\vec{a}_i - 2\vec{z}_i^T M\vec{a}_i + \vec{z}_i^T\vec{z}_i.
\end{align*}
Does this help? I am not sure why you expect $M^2$ to appear.

Comment: Ok, everything after the first step is clear. Why do we do $\lVert \dots \rVert^2 = (\dots)^\text{T}(\dots )$ and not $\lVert \dots \rVert^2 = (\dots)(\dots )$?

Comment: Because you are dealing with vectors. Let $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $xy$ makes no sense but $x^Ty$ does.

Comment: This was the missing stone. Nut sure why I missed that for so long. Thank you. If you write this as an answer I'll accept this, so this question can be marked as solved.

Comment: I think my confusion comes from how I first learned about vector math in school. There we had this notation: $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}d\\e\\f\end{pmatrix}$ → scalar product and $\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}d\\e\\f\end{pmatrix}$ →cross product. So it is normal for me to multiply two standing vectors. And then in university every prof preferred its own syntax on how to write vectors, like $\underline{x}=\vec{x}=\mathbf{x}$ or $\langle\vec{a},\vec{b}\rangle$ for scalar products and so on.

Comment: It is important not to confuse $xy$ with $x\cdot y$. There is no logic in the former, while there is in the latter (i.e. the dot product).

Comment: Isn't $xy = x\cdot y$? I mean $4x\sin(3x^2) = 4\cdot x\cdot \sin(3\cdot x^2)$. I just would like to have one rule-set and there $\cdot$ has no other meaning then multiplication which can also be expressed by omitting the $\cdot$. I think I'll just forget what I learned about vectors and treat everything as a matrix. Then the dimensions have to match on multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not expect $M^2$ to appear. Consider the following

\begin{align*} 
\left\lVert M\vec{a}_i - \vec{z}_i\right\rVert^2 &= \Big(M\vec{a}_i - \vec{z}_i\Big)^T\Big( M\vec{a}_i - \vec{z}_i\Big),\\
&= \Big( (M\vec{a}_i)^T - \vec{z}_i^T\Big)\Big( M\vec{a}_i - \vec{z}_i\Big),\\
&= \Big( \vec{a}_i^TM^T - \vec{z}_i^T\Big)\Big( M\vec{a}_i - \vec{z}_i\Big),\\
&= \vec{a}_i^TM^TM\vec{a}_i -\vec{a}_i^TM^T\vec{z}_i - \vec{z}_i^T M\vec{a}_i + \vec{z}_i^T\vec{z}_i,\\
&= \vec{a}_i^TM^TM\vec{a}_i - 2\vec{z}_i^T M\vec{a}_i + \vec{z}_i^T\vec{z}_i.
\end{align*}

Note $\vec{z}_i^T M\vec{a}_i = \vec{a}_i^TM^T \vec{z}_i$ because scalars are symmetric. Also, let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, we have $\| x \|^2 = x^Tx$.